# How to encode an array of numbers in python with piheean?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, encryption

I have this code which encrypts a list of numbers.

```
import piheaan as heaan
import numpy as np

# Step 1. Setting Parameters
params = heaan.ParameterPreset.SS7
context = heaan.make_context(params)
# Step 2. Generating Keys
key_dir_path = "./keys"
sk = heaan.SecretKey(context)
keygen = heaan.KeyGenerator(context, sk)
keygen.gen_common_keys()
pack = keygen.keypack
# Step 3. Encrypt Message to Ciphertext - with a specific vector
enc = heaan.Encryptor(context)
log_slots = 3
msg = heaan.Message(log_slots) # number_of slots = pow(2, log_slots)
for i, value in  in enumerate([2,5,4,3]):
    msg[i] = value
ctxt = heaan.Ciphertext(context)
enc.encrypt(msg, pack, ctxt)
# Step 4. multiply ciphertexts(i.e. square a ciphertext)
eval = heaan.HomEvaluator(context, pack)
ctxt_out = heaan.Ciphertext(context)
eval.mult(ctxt, ctxt, ctxt_out)
# Step 5. decrypt the ciphertext by Decryptor.
dec = heaan.Decryptor(context)
msg_out = heaan.Message()
dec.decrypt(ctxt_out, sk, msg_out)

#output - it has 9 slots (2 to the power of 3), so only encrypts the first 4 in this case.
msg_out
[ (4.000000+0.000000j), (25.000000+0.000000j), (16.000000+0.000000j), (9.000000+0.000000j), (0.000000+0.000000j), (0.000000+0.000000j), (0.000000+0.000000j), (0.000000+0.000000j) ]
```

However, my actual data is in the form of an array, e.g.:

```
l1 = [2, 5, 4, 3]
l2 = [1, 2, 2, 3]
..

arr_in = np.array([l1,l2])
arr_in
# array([[2, 5, 4, 3],
#       [1, 2, 2, 3]])
```

I have tried this

```
for i, value in np.ndenumerate(arr):
    msg[i] = value
```

but it does not work with the piheean's message format giving an error.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [44], in <cell line: 5>()
      4 msg = heaan.Message(log_slots) # number_of slots = pow(2, log_slots)
      5 for i, value in np.ndenumerate(arr):
----> 6     msg[i] = value
      7 ctxt = heaan.Ciphertext(context)
      8 enc.encrypt(msg, pack, ctxt)

TypeError: __setitem__(): incompatible function arguments. The following argument types are supported:
    1. (self: piheaan.Message, idx: int, value: complex) -> None

Invoked with: [ (0.000000+0.000000j), (0.000000+0.000000j), (0.000000+0.000000j), (0.000000+0.000000j), (0.000000+0.000000j), (0.000000+0.000000j), (0.000000+0.000000j), (0.000000+0.000000j) ], (0, 0), 2
```

how can I write the code which essentially takes each list from my array, arr_in,  encrypts it and outputs it as an array of the form, arr_out, array([[4, 25,16,9], [1,4,4,9]]) ?

Comment: In the original code
```python
for i, value in  in enumerate([2,5,4,3]):
    msg[i] = value
```
`i` is an integer, but in you example
```python
for i, value in np.ndenumerate(arr):
    msg[i] = value
```
`i` is not an integer. The docs here suggest it is some kind of tuple? https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndenumerate.html

Answer (score 1):

If you print this :

```
for i, value in np.ndenumerate(arr_in):
  print(i,value)

(0, 0) 2
(0, 1) 1
(0, 2) 5
(0, 3) 2
(1, 0) 4
(1, 1) 2
(1, 2) 3
(1, 3) 3
```

You were trying to assign `(0,0)..(1,3)` tuples to `msg[]`. That is the reason you were getting error.

Instead you can do:

```
l1 = [2, 5, 4, 3]
l2 = [1, 2, 2, 3]
arr_in = np.array(list(zip(l1, l2))).reshape((2, 4))

#output
array([[2, 1, 5, 2],
       [4, 2, 3, 3]])


new_arr = arr_in.flatten()
for i,value in enumerate(new_arr):
  print(i,value)  # you get the index as well as the value

0 2
1 1
2 5
3 2
4 4
5 2
6 3
7 3
```

`msg` is `2**3` .i.e. `8` values

```
[ (0.000000+0.000000j), (0.000000+0.000000j), (0.000000+0.000000j), (0.000000+0.000000j), (0.000000+0.000000j), (0.000000+0.000000j), (0.000000+0.000000j), (0.000000+0.000000j) ]

for i, value in enumerate(new_arr):
    msg[i] = value

print(msg)

[ (2.000000+0.000000j), (1.000000+0.000000j), (5.000000+0.000000j), (2.000000+0.000000j), (4.000000+0.000000j), (2.000000+0.000000j), (3.000000+0.000000j), (3.000000+0.000000j) ]
```

Comment: ok, that works. I get a message of 8 elements long. however, I need to split this message back into two lists (an array of two lists).  as each of these represents a separate encoded sentence. OR, I need to encode each of these lists, one by one, and then append them into an array. unfortunately, the piheean documentation does not tell much how to achieve this, https://pypi.org/project/pi-heaan/.